# How to make sure Firebase ML kit for vision image generates new ID for face for every new face in app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase ML Kit's Firebase Vision API to detect faces and track IDs of faces in all photos. It generates IDs starting as `0`, `1` and so on as long as user has the app installed. When the user uninstalls the app and installs and login with same account then it again starts generating IDs from `0`, `1` and so on. How can I make sure it generates a new ID for every new face it detects.

```
Future assignFaceId(File image) async{
    print('Face detect called');
    final visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(image);
    final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(FaceDetectorOptions(
      enableTracking: true,
      mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate
    ));
    final face = await faceDetector.processImage(visionImage);
    print(face[0].trackingId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question!

The face tracking ID is not used to recognize faces, and it won't tell you whether these two faces belong to the same person or not. The [face tracking ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder#enableTracking()) is  used in streaming mode, where it helps to track the same face in the consecutive frames.

In your case, if you only want to assign each face a new ID without recognizing them as the same person, you could assign an ID yourself, and keep the count in SharedPreference. Hope that helps.